# NGINX Redirect All Requests Matching URL with Parameters to Subdomain

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a website that is also serving api requests to an app on the main domain. I would like to send all matching /api requests to an api subdomain.

For example I would like https://example.com/api + https://example.com/api/some_action + https://example.com/api/some_action?params1=somevalue&params2=value2....   to redirect to the same url structure but just on the subdomain.

So for the above example:

https://example.com/api 
-> https://api.example.com/api

https://example.com/api/some_action 
-> https://api.example.com/api/some_action

https://example.com/api/some_action?params1=somevalue&params2=value2.... 
-> https://api.example.com/api/some_action?params1=somevalue&params2=value2....

For all types of requests (get, posts etc) as well.  So far I have tried this in the server directive for the main domain (in the 443 SSL server directive)

```
location ~ /api(.*)$ {
  return 301 https://api.example.com/api/$request_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

The result I get when performing a simple GET request on  https://api.example.com/api/some_action?param1=value ... is https://api.example.com//some_action without parameters and missing the api.

Comment: Please clarify your last paragraph. The configuration you have in your question should insert `/api/api/` and double the arguments, as `$request_uri` contains both the `/api` and arguments already.

Comment: @RichardSmith its a rails app and the controller is called "api"  that serves all api request.  The subdomain is called api.example.com so it's a little confusing but will be api.example.com/api/action  for example in the new setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `example.com/api/foo?bar` to `api.example.com/api/foo?bar` you should use:

```
location ^~ /api {
    return 307 https://api.exemple.com$request_uri;
}
```

The `$request_uri` variable contains the original request, including the `/api/` prefix and the query sring.

The `^~` operator gives this `location` precedence (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details). The 307 status code maintains GET/POST through the redirection (see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for more).

Comment: Thanks this works for the most part but I'm running into an issue that my be related to something else... Do you know if HTTP Headers are also forwarded (redirected)? I use an authentication token in the header to like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization and are getting errors on the api.example.com domain logs to authentication requests that are 307 thru the location directiave above.

Comment: This feels like a whole new question. IDK if authentication works between a domain and a subdomain.

Comment: fair enough so far this answer has been working for me and thanks for your answer!